# Overflow reservoir bubbles after driving not overheating

Tags: ford, coolant, radiator, windstar

My 95 Ford Windstar just had the radiator replaced. After driving there is bubbling in the overflow res. , engine is not overheating and water seems cool to touch in reservoir. I can smell antifreeze under the hood but do not see any leaks. I have used a block sealer in this motor two years ago. Is it possible that there is another crack in the block or could this be something else?

Comment: Did you change the radiator cap when you changed the radiator? Was the system properly burped?

Answer (score 1):

Kindly check out if the your vehicle is using high presser reservoir container or low accumulated pressure,

1. if your vehicle is using high pressure accumulated container, please check the container breather cup or hose maybe the loading release valve is sucked. 
   In this case you have to change the radiator cup and reservoir cup.
2. If your vehicle is using low accumulated pressure reservoir container then it has no breather on reservoir cup, or no radiator cup. It means you have a crack on reservoir hose, or on reservoir itself, or the clips are not well tightened.

   In this case replace reservoir container or pipe or tighten the clips.

   IMPORTANT INFORMATION,
   We cant suggest on thermostat: if thermostat is faulty we will have engine overheating, and if there is clogging we will still have engine overheating.